# PHP MYSQL PDO -> Fatal Error 23000 eventhough a special procedure is in place

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table in my db. My table has several fields including an auto-incremented id field set as primary key, and one other field called 'reference' that I did set as unique. To populate that table, I have a php script that insert records in that table using pdo. Every time an insert has been made successfully (meaning the 'reference' did not exist in the table), I increment a variable called $newOnes. If the value 'reference' is already in the table, an exception with the code 23000 is triggered. In that case, I increment another variable called $doublons. Unfortunately my script is triggering a fatal error with exception 23000 **when the while loop is "handling" the last record of the table**. And I do not get it. Thank you in advance for your help. Cheers. Marc.

My php code:

```
try {
  $connexion = connexion('localhost', 'user', 'user', 'mydb');
  $connexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $qry_bat = $connexion->query('SELECT...');
  $ins_db = $connexion->prepare('INSERT...');
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

while($row = $qry_bat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  try {
    $ins_db->execute(array(...));
    $newOnes++;
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() != 23000) {
      echo '<span class="msg-alert">'.$e->getMessage().'</span>';
    } else {
      $doublons++;
    }
  }
}
```

The fatal error I am getting (note that line 22 refers to the while(...) line):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:  
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'theFieldContentOfTheLastRecordOfTheTable' for key 'theFieldNameReference' in  
/myFilePath/file.php:22 Stack trace: #0 /myFilePath/file.php(22): PDOStatement->fetch(2)  
#1 {main} thrown in /myFilePath/file.php on line 22
```

EDIT //////////

original table (things to mentionne):
auto incremented id

table to insert in (things to mentionne):
auto incremented on id field
UNIQUE INDEX on reference

Comment: It doesn't help explain why you're not catching the exception, but you *could* `INSERT` all of your values in one go, using `INSERT IGNORE ... VALUES (...), (...), ...`, then call [`$ins_db->rowCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) to discover the value of `$newOnes` (from which `$doublons` can be calculated as `$qry_bat->rowCount() - $newOnes`).  Indeed, you can probably save yourself executing `$qry_bat` altogether by using [`INSERT IGNORE INTO ... SELECT ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: Is the above workaround no use?  Or do you very specifically want an answer on why the exception is uncaught?

Comment: Hello eggyval. I would like to understand why that exception is triggered... Thanks

Comment: similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625348/try-catch-block-not-working-with-pdo-statement-and-foreach), in which the OP states "*Upgrading PHP version to 5.3.10 seems to fix this issue*".  Could be a PHP bug?

Comment: looks like [this open bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42322).

Comment: One of the basic rules of exceptions is "Don't pee in your pants to see if your fly is open". To use an exception to check if a likely condition is met, is bad style.

Comment: So JannieT, any better suggestion to increment a variable on duplicate?

Comment: @Marc: one better suggestion would be the workaround mentioned in my first comment above?

Comment: @Marc, when you refer to someone's comment remember to precede their name with an at sign otherwise they don't get notified. The accepted answer solves your problem and avoids using exceptions to "test" for a likely condition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(*Upgrading to an answer*)

Looks like [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42322), which is still open after almost five years; try instead:

```
while (true) {
  try {
    $row = $qry_bat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!$row) break;
    $ins_db->execute(array(...));
    $newOnes++;
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() != 23000) {
      echo '<span class="msg-alert">'.$e->getMessage().'</span>';
    } else {
      $doublons++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I already found a workaround by putting a try before my while loop and a catch at the end. That is working. Nevertheless, I would like to understand why the original code is not working as there is not reason it shouldn't...

Comment: Very dubious bug, and even more dubious is the fact that in this case there are 2 separate PDOStatement objects.

Comment: @Marc: I suspect the PDO connection is not resetting its error state after the `INSERT` fails, so the next call to `fetch()` throws that same exception (outside of your original `try` block).  If that is indeed what's happening, it's definitely a bug / undocumented behaviour (and there's no means by which to reset the PDO object's error state); an alternative workaround would be to use two PDO objects - one for the fetch and one for the insert.

Comment: The thing is, the insert fails many times during the loop as I have multiple doublons, and everything is working fine. Except when the while loop is running the last loop. So according to the fact that the "inserts fail procedure" is working fine for all loops (except the last one), I assume that the PDO connexion manages to reset its error state properly after an inserts fail...

Comment: @Marc: It's entirely possible that such a "throwing of past exception" bug occurs only when `fetch()` fails due to no further records in the recordset.  Whatever it is, this very much looks like a bug.

Comment: I will wait a little for possible other explanations. If nothing else comes, I will take that explanation (bug) as an answer. Thks both of you for having taking time to try to help out...

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace shows the exception taking place in the fetch which is outside of the try/catch blocks.

The SELECT statement is triggering:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'theFieldContentOfTheLastRecordOfTheTable'
```

There's a unique key named **theFieldContentOfTheLastRecordOfTheTable** that it's conflicting with.

Can you post the schema for us to see how this could affect integrity?

Comment: Hello Mihai. I understand the Exception. What I do not understand is why it is triggered...

Comment: The stack trace shows the exception taking place in the **fetch** which is outside of the **try/catch** blocks.

Comment: Absolutely... And I don't understand why that error is triggered.

Comment: I don't get it either, yet, why a presumably simple select would trigger an integrity violation.

Answer (score 0):

Look for dirty / duplicate data ALREADY in that column. Some apps allow a "loose" constraint to be applied AFTER data is already captured. This may have happen in your case.