# Data successfully inserted, yet execute() returns false

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have searched here for answer to my problem. Some might had already answered here with other versions or drivers. This answer would help me a lot to go forward in my developments.

My `PDOStatement::prepare()` is returning true. But my `PDOStatement::execute();` returning false.

Whereas, The rows are inserting successfully in the database. I have searched for the problem in php.net as well as PDO documentations. My search went in vein.

My simple insert code is as follows:

```
// get current rank into a variable //

$sql = 'SELECT count(email)+1 AS RANK FROM users_main';

$pre = $dbc->prepare($sql);

if($pre){

    $pre->execute(array($email)); // <-- working good ... 

    $res = $pre->fetchObject();

    if($res)$rank=(string)$res->RANK;else $rank='';
}   

// now inserting new user into the table as per his new rank.   

$usercode = substr(md5(gzencode($email)),0,10);
$activationcode = md5(gzencode(substr(md5($email),0,10)));


// inserting the actual row into db ... 

$sql = "INSERT INTO users_main(email,usercode,activation_code,current_rank) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$pre = $dbc->prepare($sql);


// debugging ... 
echo '<pre>';

try {   
    $pre->execute(array($email,$usercode,$activationcode,$rank));    // <-- PROBLEM IS HERE . RETURNING FALSE.  
}catch(Exception $e){   
    echo $e->getMessage();  // <--  NO ERROR MESSAGE    
}


echo '<br><br>';

print_r($dbc->errorInfo());    //   <-- here sqlstate is 0000

echo '</pre>';

    /*$emailSubject = 'Welcome Mail!';
    $emailLink = '?b='.$activationCode;
    if(insertEmailQueue('W',$email,$emailSubject,$emailLink))return true;else return false;
    }*/
```

Adding to the above information, I have checked the datatype of each columns I am trying to insert into. Everything looks fine.
Replying this question would really help me a lot.

### UPDATE

I was debugging above code and I was trying to change to get what is the error. I have changed the code as below :

```
try {

    $res = $pre->execute(array($email,$usercode,$activationcode,$rank));    // <-- PROBLEM IS HERE . RETURNING FALSE.

}catch(PDOException $e){    
    echo $e->getMessage();  // <--  NO ERROR MESSAGE    
}


echo '<br><br>';

print_r($dbc->errorInfo());    //   <-- here sqlstate is 0000

echo '<br><br>';

print_r($dbc->errorCode());

echo '<br><br>';

print_r($pre->errorCode());

echo '</pre>';
```

The result was as below :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)


00000

23000    // <-- this is a fatal error as per the documentation.
```

Comment: Nowhere I see how can you tell that execute returns false.

Comment: is your pdo error mode set to exceptions?

Comment: I am dumping the result and it shows as `bool(false)` and I could not catch any error message too. I am repeating my words, rows are successfully inserting.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes. It is set..

Comment: You try, change "Exception" to "PDOException"

Comment: You are apparently dumping something else, because nothing relevant can be seen in the code you posted. Given you have your data inserted, your code is working all righ and your problem is a mere measurement error

Comment: @AhmetErkanÇELİK I tried as you said, still no error message caught.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I am calling this function from other page like `$result = insertUsers($email);` and i am dumping the `$result` as well as the entire statement execution line `var_dump($pre->execute(  array(.....)   ));`. Still I cant find any positive output. I found an alternative method to escape this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430005/php-mysql-pdo-fatal-error-23000-eventhough-a-special-procedure-is-in-place . But i want to know why does that returns false anyway?

Comment: Dumping $result makes absolutely no sense and **should** return you NULL, which is **normal**. Given all that, I am no wonder you are still struggling to find an error that never ever existed.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thank you very much for providing me a hint, how to catch the problem. The code `SQLSTATE 23000` is a fatal error at MySQL database, where an unacceptable character is being forced to insert into a column. Escaping this insert variables did the magic. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

After a two days long struggle to know what the error was, finally I found by trying to get error and other internet references. What I have changed is

```
    .... 

    // now inserting new user into the table as per his new rank.   

    $usercode = addslashes(substr(md5(gzencode($email)),0,10));
    $activationcode = addslashes(md5(gzencode(substr(md5($email),0,10))));


    ....
```

`addslashes()` is one of the primitive way to escape the unacceptable characters.

I still wonder, why did MySQL accept the statement, insert the rows and returned false after inserting. I will update the answer if I find out why this weird problem occurs.

Thank you every one for helping me.